# In the given figure find angle x.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I approached it these ways-

1)Constructing parallel lines and then using similarity

2)Trying exterior angle property

3)Constructing perpendiculars

I am not able to understand the suitable construction.

[image]

Comment: Using trigonometry you can solve this quite easily.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Draw $\angle ABE = 15^0$. Then what is $\angle BED$? Can you show $\triangle BDE, \triangle BEA \,$ and $\triangle BEC$ are isosceles? Also what is $\angle CED$? From there, it is straightforward to show $\angle C = 75^0$.

Just an observation - $E$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Congrats on 10k! :)

Comment: @Math Lover I am able to prove △,△ isosceles how do I go about proving △ isosceles?

Comment: @cosmo5  Thank you! I guess the current situation gave time for maths, working from home :) Btw this solution was accidental. I first posted a different solution and then noticed this in the diagram so changed it :)

Comment: @Ralf $DE = BD = \frac{1}{2} CD$ so $\angle DCE = 30^0$ or $DE = CD \cos 60^0$. Basically $\angle CED = 90^0$.

Comment: Yup got that :). Also if you don't mind me asking how do we go about saving questions which require construction. I always get strangled when I try to find the suitable construction.

Comment: I am not great at it myself. A lot of angle chasing problems require combination of equilateral triangle, cyclic quadrilateral, isosceles triangles and patience. When lengths are given and you see angle of $60^0, 30^0$, it is hint enough to check how you can construct isosceles / equilateral triangles. I have seen couple of people on the site who are good at it - cosmo5, player..., I will pose the question to @cosmo5 too. In the end, practice is the key.

Comment: @Ralf Improve your recognition/observation skills. Draw clear diagram and look everywhere. And whenever you learn something new, add it to your database, don't forget it :)

Comment: I noticed that your background shows an interest in Geometry.  Although my general math comprehension is about that of an undergraduate math major, my (high school only) Geometry class has 50+ years of cobwebs, although I was able to provide the alternative *answer*.  On my *todo* list is to find Geometry sources (i.e. books or [preferred] free pdf's) that will take my Geometry knowledge/intuition/sophistication from ground zero to on a par with a recent math major (under)-graduate.  Any recommendations for Geometry sources?

Comment: @user2661923 Happy New Year! There may be newer books that are better but based on the books I had read, Kiselev's Geometry is a good start to clear all the cobwebs. Elementary Geometry by Edwin Moise is also a great book.

Comment: @user2661923 If you search the internet, Kiselev's Planimetry is also available for free to download.

Answer (score 2):

I recently added two sections to the end of this answer: an Addendum which moderately refines the original answer, and an Addendum-1 which significantly refines the original answer.

---

Unclear if the following method is *off-limits*, given the tags of **geometry** and **euclidean geometry**.

The problem is routinely solved via double use of the law of sines.

Initially, since the small triangle at the bottom has angles of $45^\circ, 120^\circ, 15^\circ, ~$ you know that the base of the triangle is $$\frac{\sin(120^\circ)}{\sin(15^\circ)} \approx 3.346065215.$$

With the base of the triangle *solved*, you also know that the large triangle has angles $x^\circ, (135 - x)^\circ, 45^\circ.$

The second application of the law of sines yields

$$\frac{\sin(x^\circ)}{3.346065215} = \frac{\sin(135-x)^\circ}{3}.$$

You also know that

$$\sin(135-x)^\circ = \sin(135^\circ)\cos(x^\circ) - 
\sin(x^\circ)\cos(135^\circ).$$

You also know that for any angle $\theta$,

$$\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1.$$

Putting this all together, I computed that

$$x = 75^\circ.$$

A variation at the end would be to compute $\tan(x^\circ)$ and then feed in the computed number to a calculator's ArcTan function.

**Note**
A way of verifying that $x = 75^\circ$ is an exact answer is to note that

$$\sin(15^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}}{2} ~\text{and}~ \sin(75^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}{2}.$$

---

**Addendum**

I was bothered by how inelegant my original answer was, so I thought that I'd take another crack at it.

There are three key identities:

$$\sin(15^\circ) \times \sin(75^\circ) = \frac{1}{4}. \tag1$$

$$\sin^2(75^\circ) = \frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{4}.\tag2$$

$$3 + \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{6}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}. \tag3$$

As indicated in my original answer, the base of the triangle is

$$\frac{\sin(120^\circ)}{\sin(15^\circ)} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \times [4 \times \sin(75)^\circ] = 2\sqrt{3}\sin(75^\circ).$$

Denoting the left side of the large triangle by $c$, the law of cosines 
[i.e. $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos(c)$]
may be used to compute

$$c^2 = [12\sin^2(75^\circ)] + 9 - \left[2 \times 3 \times 2\sqrt{3}\sin(75^\circ) \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right]$$

$$= \left[12 \times \left(\frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right] ~+~ 9 ~-~ 
\left[12\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\times \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}{2}\right]$$

$$= \left[3 \times \left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)\right] ~+~ 9 ~-~ 
\left[3\left(\sqrt{6}\right)
\times \left(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}\right)\right].$$

Using the identity of equation (3) above, this expression may be simplified to

$$= \left[3 \times \left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)\right] 
~+~ 9 ~-~ 
\left[3 \times \left(3 + \sqrt{3}\right)\right]$$

$$= 6.$$

In the large triangle, with the side length of $\sqrt{6}$ opposite the $45^\circ$ angle, and the side length of $2\sqrt{3}\sin(75^\circ)$ opposite the $x^\circ$ angle, the law of sines may again be used to compute

$$\sin(x^\circ) = 2\sqrt{3}\sin(75^\circ) \times 
\frac{\sin(45^\circ)}{\sqrt{6}}$$

$$= \sin(75^\circ) \times \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} \times \sqrt{6}} = \sin(75^\circ) \implies $$

$$x = (75^\circ).$$

---

**Addendum-1**

Construct a (perpendicular) altitude from the lower left vertex of the triangle to the right side of the triangle.  Assume that the intersection of the altitude with the right side of the triangle creates a 45-45-90 right triangle, with each leg of the triangle equal to $(1 + y)$.

This means that the constructed altitude also creates a 60-30-90 triangle, with one of the legs equal to $(y)$.

Since the legs of the 45-45-90 triangle are equal, the length of the constructed altitude is **also** $(1+y).$

Since the tangent of $60^\circ = \sqrt{3},$ this implies that

$$\frac{1 + y}{y} = \sqrt{3} \implies y(\sqrt{3} - 1) = 1 \implies y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} - 1} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} - 1} \times 
\frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{\sqrt{3} + 1} = \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2}.$$

This implies that the constructed altitude has also created a right triangle with one of the angles = $(x^\circ)$ such that

$$\tan(x^\circ) = \frac{1+y}{2-y} ~=~
\frac{1 + \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2}}{2 - \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2}}$$

$$= \frac{2 + \sqrt{3} + 1}{4 - \sqrt{3} - 1} = \frac{3 + \sqrt{3}}{3 - \sqrt{3}} = \tan(75^\circ) \implies x = (75^\circ).$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is almost similar to Math Lover's solution...

Draw $AH$ perpendicular to $BD$. In the right triangle AHD:
$$\widehat{HAD}=90^o-60^o=30^o \quad \Rightarrow \quad HD=\frac12AD=1 $$
Draw HC and observe that triangle $DHC$ is isosceles:
$$ HD=1=DC \quad \Rightarrow \quad \widehat{DHC} = \widehat{DCH} = \frac12(180^o-120^o)=30^o$$
Now observe that triangle $HAC$ is also isosceles:
$$\widehat{HAC}=\widehat{HCA}=30^0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad HA=HC \qquad(1)$$
In triangle $DBC$ note that $\widehat{DBC}=180^o-(120^o+45^o)=15^o$.

Now, observe that triangle $HBC$ is isosceles too:
$$\widehat{HCB} = \widehat{ACB}-\widehat{ACH}=45^o-30^o=15^o $$
$$\widehat{HCB}=\widehat{HBC}=15^o \quad \Rightarrow \quad HC=HB \qquad(2) $$
From (1) and (2) we conclude that $HA=HB$ and that the right triangle $AHB$ is isosceles, which means $\widehat{HAB}=45^o$. Now we can say that
$$\widehat{BAC}=\widehat{BAH}+\widehat{HAC}=45^o+30^o=75^o $$